# Multiple UIPickers IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Hello guys thanks for reading this question. So i have been stuck on this issue for a while now and need a bit of help. I am attempting to implement multiple pickers in IOS but they do not come out as planned. I successfully done one picker by itself but attempting to add another one in the same view i have ran into problems. [image: Image of problem in storyboard.]

So at first i thought it was a problem to do with this line of code. But when using the return 1: it would just return the same ui picker twice. And return 2 returns the same issue as above but with two rows.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView {

/*

return 1;

*/

if(pickerView == _picker) {
    return _colourSourceArray.count;
} else if(_picker == _mustachepicker) {
    return _mustacheArray.count;
}

}
```

Both of my datasources are linked to the same view, would this be causing the problem?

What my .h looks like:

```
////// Frame Colour Picker
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *colourSourceArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *selectedcolour;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
////// Mustahce Picker
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *mustachepicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *mustacheArray;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *selectedMostache;
/////////////////////////
```

And my .m methods:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSInteger comp = 0;
if(_picker == _mustachepicker){
    comp= _mustacheArray.count;
} else if(pickerView == _picker) {
    comp= _colourSourceArray.count;
}
return comp;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSString *title;
if(_picker == _mustachepicker){
    title= _mustacheArray[row];
} else if(pickerView == _picker){
    title = _colourSourceArray[row];
}
return title;
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row    inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if(_picker == _mustachepicker){
    NSString *mustacheString= _mustacheArray[row];
    NSLog(mustacheString);
    _selectedMostache=mustacheString;
} else if(pickerView == _picker){
    NSString *resultString = _colourSourceArray[row];
    _selectedcolour= resultString;
    NSLog(resultString);
}
NSLog(_selectedcolour);
NSLog(_selectedMostache);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide the crash log?

Comment: just comes up with (lldb) when i click on the view

Comment: Okay, this might not help but try this: always `return 1;` in `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:`. Also, your `else if (_mostacheArray)` should change to `else if (pickerView == _mustachepicker)`. But anyway, try returning 1 always.

Comment: Just tried that and get a thread breakpoint after the return 1;

Comment: When you hit a breakpoint, which method are you in, in the stack presented in left panel?

Answer (score 1):

As you have created two different pickers, then why are you setting the `tag` to the pickers just compare the UIPicker in there DataSource and Delegate methods like this

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    if(pickerView == _picker) {
         return _colourSourceArray.count;
    } else if(_picker == _mustachepicker) {
         return _mostacheArray.count;
    }
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSInteger comp = 0;
    if(_picker == _mustachepicker){
         comp= _mostacheArray.count;
    } else if(pickerView == _picker) {
         comp= _colourSourceArray.count;
    }
    return comp;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *title;
    if(_picker == _mustachepicker){
         title= _mostacheArray[row];
    } else if(pickerView == _picker){
         title = _colourSourceArray[row];
    }
    return title;
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   if(_picker == _mustachepicker){
         NSString *mostacheString= _mostacheArray[row];
         NSLog(mostacheString);
        _selectedMostache=mostacheString;
   } else if(pickerView == _picker){
         NSString *resultString = _colourSourceArray[row];
         _selectedcolour= resultString;
         NSLog(resultString);
   }
   NSLog(_selectedcolour);
   NSLog(_selectedMostache);
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the code, i have attempted to implement it but now i have run into another error, http://postimg.org/image/ip5db0jwn/
Think it may be to do with the number of components in picker view maybe.

Comment: check `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`